# What is a sample path of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Given a probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P$) and a measurable space ($S,\Sigma$), and an S-valued stochastic process { $X_t : t \in T$ }(assume every $X_t$ is i.i.d). What does a sample paths mean?  From the definition, it's 'the function on $T$ to the range of the process which assigns to each $t$ the value $X_t(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a previously given fixed point in the domain of the process.

But if the $\omega$ is fixed, then the value of each $X_t$ should be the same, which seems not true. What's the problem here?

Comment: This common confusion comes from misunderstanding the definition of the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ (i.e., defining it over the outcomes of a ''single'' experiment, instead of the product space of outcomes of all $T$ experiments). e.g., for an infinite coin tossing (Bernoulli) process, the sample space $\Omega$ should be the set of all infinite binary strings. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3426954/definition-of-sample-path-of-stochastic-process?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that it's simply not true that "then the value of each $X_j$ should be the same".

Hmm. Example: Say $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ with $P$ equal to Lebesgue measure. Define $X,Y:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ by $X(s,t)=t$ and $Y(s,t)=s$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are iid, but $X(\omega)\ne Y(\omega)$.

Comment: That really make sense! so the point is that the mappings of each random variable are not the same...Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi! I just realise that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent...because $Y$ can only take the value of $1-X$..

Comment: @WenyiQin For some reason I just noticed your comment. Good point - thanks. I believe the error's fixed in the edit...

Answer (score 24):

To get a good intuition for the definition at first, it can help to *look at* some sample paths. From Bernt Øksendal's [Stochastic Differential Equations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540047581):

[image: Sample paths]

The image shows five sample paths of a geometric Brownian motion process<sup>†</sup> $\{X_t\}_{t\ge0}$. The paths are different functions of $t$ (which you may think of as representing *time*). Each one of them shows the values that $X$ takes over time under a specific outcome ($\omega_1,\dots,\omega_5$) in the sample space $\Omega.$

Notice by contrast that the expected value $E[X_t]$ of the process is also drawn (as a smooth function of $t$) and that it is obtained by "averaging" over all of the sample paths according to the law of the process.

---

<sup>†</sup> As pointed out in the comments, what is shown is an approximation to a geometric Brownian motion process.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but there is no answer in your post, not even an attempt at answering the question. There is also a mistake: the expected value of a geometric brownian motion is definitely a sample path. In fact any continuous function on an interval (0,) starting at 0 is a sample path of brownian motion. What Øksendal shows are sample paths of a geometric random walk (approximating GBM) picked at random (and regularity, in a suitable sense, is not a probable event). While a smooth function on (0,) will not be "very probable" in a suitable (Wiener) sense.

Comment: @plm I fixed the last part. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 12):

Each random variable $X_t$ is an $\mathcal F$-measurable function $\omega\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ from $\Omega$ to $S$. The stochastic process $X$ may therefore be viewed as  a function of two variables $\Omega\times T\ni (\omega,t)\mapsto X_t(\omega)\in S$. For each fixed $\omega\in\Omega$ we have the partial function $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$; this is the *sample path* of $X$ corresponding to the sample point $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you. So which functions on $T$ are sample paths, ie what characterizes sample paths of X ? In the case of usual brownian motion all continuous functions starting at 0 are sample paths. Is there a canonical function space on T associated to a stochastic process or are there arbitrary choices involved. And relatedly: what functions on $\Omega\times T$ correspond to a given stochastic process ? Perhaps this is easier (or more difficult) to answer generally. The answer is probably a function of the type of stochastic process considered.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question in general -apart from repeating that given a stochastic process on $\Omega$ sample paths are the set image of the function $\omega\mapsto X_t(\omega)\in(\text{Functions on }T$); see also my question in comment to John Dawkins.

But here is a clarification for your last remark. Let's consider the random walk on $[0,N]$. Usually one begins with iid rv $X=\pm 1$ with probability 1/2. The simplest way to build a single such random variable is on a 2 element sample space $\Omega$ but then if we define several such variables on $\Omega$ they will not be independent. So we take the product $\Omega^N$ to define $N$ such variables $X_i$ each depending on a different $\Omega$ factor, say the ith one; then they are iid. Then we sum them to get the random walk $(Z_n)_n=(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)_n$. It is more natural to pick another sample space. Each element of our random walk sample space $\Omega^N$ corresponds to a function from $[0,N]$ to $\Omega$. But then we may compose with our random variable $Z_N$ to get a function from $[0,N]$ to $\mathbb R$, that is discrete paths, and we get a measure on such paths. The Wiener measure on continuous functions on $[0,T]$ (that is paths) starting at $0$ is constructed as a limit of such random walk measures, suitably scaled, using general existence/convergence theorems. When we have a measure on all paths (with some restrictions) we may consider the probability of subsets: for instance smooth paths, or differentiable with bounded derivative, etc. And they may turn out to have very small measure, and therefore sampling functions randomly according to the measure we are considering will very rarely yield a function in those spaces. It turns out that smooth or otherwise regular functions are very rare for the Wiener measure. It can be proved for instance that almost surely for the Wiener measure a (sample=continuous starting at $0$ in this case) path is nowhere differentiable, that is why when we pick a sample path of (geometric) brownian motion we have those typical irregular curves. Another way to generate such a picture is to flip a coin and sum the trials one by one, with sufficiently many points close to one another to fit in a single image as in dafinguzman's answer. The probability for each path we generate this way, is that of the random walk of the length we stop at evaluated on this path (the singleton of this path), and we know that it converges in a suitable sense to the Wiener measure -which gives probability $0$ to such singletons, but again we may consider suitable sets of paths.

In conclusion i would say that the notion of "sample path" does not really belong to mathematics but to physics or psychology or some other science which generates natural ex/samples. The case of brownian motion is typical. If we try to define a mathematical concept we would say something like "path in a set of positive measure defined naturally". Then the question is to define "natural". Usually what is done is to resort to logic or computer science: we define elementary operations and what is natural is what is simple, accessible and attractive to the human mind. So we could try defining (discrete) "sample path" as "path generated by making at each time a uniformly random choice among a finite set and applying a 'computationally simple' procedure" (for instance an algebraic operation like summation). Then the continuous sample paths would be those suitably approximated by such discrete ones. We can also generalize paths to functions on lattices and vector spaces. Etc.