# distributional identity implies pathwise identity

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm starting / dabbling with equalities of random variables and I'm seeking for help. I haven't study deeply measure theory and probability theory so it is hard for me to go deeper in proofs by myself.

My problem is the following. I'm still not able to grasp the whole concept of sample path of a random variable.

I get the idea that there is a difference between :

**1. "the distributional identity :"**
$$ B_t- B_s \overset{d}{=} B_{t-s}$$ which means both sides share a common distribution.

**2.   "pathwise identity : "**
$$\forall \omega \in \Omega \colon B_t (\omega) - B_s (\omega ) = B_{t-s} (\omega) $$

---

> but I don't get whether one is stronger than the other. Is one implying the other ?

I think that 1 does not imply 2 : because you can have the same distribution while not beeing equal as random variable ( example of the accepted answer here : [What is a sample path of a stochastic process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472068/what-is-a-sample-path-of-a-stochastic-process?answertab=oldest#tab-top))

And for 2 implies 1 I think it is true. Is my intuition true ?

> If this is true, can you give me a non trivial example where (1)
>   implies (2) ? Or a sufficient condition ?

Finally, my last point is about understanding why (1) does not imply (2) in the case of a Brownian motion (cf. [Mikosch](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MtQ7DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&lpg=PA35&dq=distributional%20identity%20implies%20pathwise%20identity&source=bl&ots=f876npDi3j&sig=ACfU3U0ppHmAX2i41ihb9VRk4Xr1MGDT6w&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjInLr4_dLlAhU0XhUIHaWIDxsQ6AEwAXoECBQQAQ#v=onepage&q=distributional%20identity%20implies%20pathwise%20identity&f=false)  ). If one can explain this to me I would be so grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Notice that if $X(\omega )=Y(\omega )$ almost surely, then of course, $X\overset{d}{=}Y$. The converse doesn't hold since $X$ and $Y$ doesn't necessarily leave on the same probability space. Moreover to say that $X(\omega )=Y(\omega )$ for all $\omega \in \Omega $ is a very strong assumption. We normally rather have the equality almost surely.
- Now, $B_t(\omega )-B_s(\omega )=B_{t-s}(\omega )$ will normally never hold. Simply because $B_{t-s}$ is $\mathcal F_{t-s}$ measurable (where $\mathcal F_t=\sigma (X_t\mid s\leq t)$ is the natural filtration of $(B_t)$), whereas $B_t-B_s$ is not.

Comment: Can you please add a way that one would prove the equality almost surely from distribution equality? Or do usually people don't use the distribution to prove the equality on $\Omega$?

Comment: and is the logic of the second point that the LHS isn't $F_{t-s}$  measurable? how do you prove that?

Comment: For your first question, it's not true that $X\overset{d}{=}Y$ implies that $X=Y$ a.s. (so I don't completely understand the question). For example, $X$ and $Y$ could not leave on the same probability space (so $X(\omega )=Y(\omega )$ wouldn't have any sense in this case). But even if they leave on the same probability space, you can have $X(\omega )\neq Y(\omega )$ for all $\omega $ and $X\overset{d}{=}Y$. A very easy example would be $\Omega =\{1,2\} $, $\mathbb P(\omega )=\frac{1}{2}$, $X(\omega )=\omega $ and $Y$ is s.t. $Y(1)=2$ and $Y(2)=1$.

Comment: For your second question, by definition of $\mathcal F_t$, $B_t$ is $\mathcal F_t-$measurable for all $t$ but $B_t$ is not  $\mathcal F_u-$measurable for $u<t$.