# $|X_t - X_s|$ notation in stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, notation, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_t$ be a real stochastic process. I am new to stochastic processes and in some proofs I see inequalities such as:
$$|X_t - X_s| \leq C_1 \quad \forall |t-s| \leq C_2 \tag{1}$$
but $X$ is a function of $t$ and $\omega$, i.e. $X_t(\omega)$ so I am not sure what is meant by (1). Does this mean (1) holds uniform in $\omega$? Is this standard notation?

Comment: This is ambiguous at first glance. I see at least two possibilities : either $|X_t(\omega) - X_s(\omega)| < C_1$ a.s. for all $|t-s| < C_2$, or there is some norm involved here, something like $\mathbb E[|X_t-X_s|^2] \leq C_1$ for all $|t-s| \leq C_2$.

Comment: It could mean almost surely or surely (depending on the context). It is also possible that means $\mathbb{E}[ |X_t-X_s|^2] \le C_1$, but it is bad notation in my opinion. $\quad$ Usually most of the properties of stochastic processes are defined up to a set of measure $0$. Can you give an example of a paper (or book) in which this notation is used?

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I am following Baldi's book on stochastic calculus and assume it is the first of the two possibilities you mentioned since he explicitly uses $\mathbb{E}$ whenever he is taking an expectation. An example of an inequality without the expectation is in his proof of Lemma 2.1.

Comment: There is no square, no $\mathbb E$ and no norm involved. What a nonsense. Plug in the $\omega$ into $X_t$ and $X_s$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as mentioned in the comments and by you, this often just means almost surely: for almost every $\omega\in \Omega$ we have

$$|X_{t}(\omega)-X_{s}(\omega)|\leq C_{1}(\omega), \forall |t-s|\leq C_{2},$$

or in probability terms

$$P[|X_{t}-X_{s}|\leq C_{1}, \forall |t-s|\leq C_{2}]=1$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \int_{\Omega} 1_{|X_{t}(\omega)-X_{s}(\omega)|\leq C_{1}(\omega), \forall |t-s|\leq C_{2}} dP(\omega)=1.$$

The $C_{1}$ might just be deterministic. The $\omega$ here means that we sample a realization of the path $(X_{t})_{t\geq 0}$. See for example [What is a sample path of a stochastic process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472068/what-is-a-sample-path-of-a-stochastic-process?rq=1) for many nice answers

[image]

See for example, [Kolmogorov continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem), where an inequality for the moments implies an almost sure modulus of continuity with random constant.