# Are paths in a stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ constant if $X_t$ is identically distributed for all $t$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I've been trying to develop an intuition for stochastic processes and would like some help clearing up the following situation.

Suppose $\{X_t\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a real valued stochastic process defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Suppose all the $X_t$ are identically distributed for each $t$, for concreteness we can assume they each have distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

On one hand I would expect that the stochastic process above describes paths centered around the constant function $f(t) = 0$. In more detail, we may say that within one standard deviation all such paths would lie within the strip $[-1, 1]$ on the range. Thus we clearly see that there is a possibility for some paths to not be constant.

On the other hand we the paths are defined as follows: for each $\omega \in \Omega$ there is an associated path $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$. Since each $X_t$ is identically distributed, $X_t(\omega)$ is constant for all $t$ and fixed $\omega$. Thus we have that each path must be a constant function.

These two pictures contradict one another. Which one is correct and what error am I making in my reasoning?

Comment: If $W_t$ is a standard BM, what is the distribution of $X_t = (t + 1)^{-1/2}W_{t + 1}$?

Comment: @daisies Thank you for your comment, but I have not yet learned about Brownian motion. That is the next chapter in the textbook I am following.

Comment: Also re: the second interpretation, note that it may be that $X_t(\omega)$ may be nonconstant in $t$, but over the entire probability space the differences between $X_{t_1}(\omega), X_{t_2}(\omega)$ may still allow for them to have the same distribution. This is, for example, the case for any two RVs defined on a common probability space that are not identical a.s., but the same in distribution.

Comment: The point is that $X_t \sim N(0, 1)$ for all $t$, but is clearly (almost surely) nonconstant.

Comment: there is no "paths" there, as there is no reason to think that the points of a random function $t\mapsto X_t$ defines a continuous graph

Comment: @daisies Oh I see, so in this case $X_{t_1}$ and $X_{t_2}$ may be different but will still both be $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ distributed? I am having some trouble thinking of an example where this can be the case, could you provide an example?

Comment: @Masacroso In the book I am following they say we can interpret the underlying space $\Omega$ as the space of paths via the correspondence $\Omega \ni \omega \mapsto (t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$. The path interpretation is only once we fix $\omega$.

Comment: @CBBAM yes, I know... but the term "path" is misleading: there is nothing similar to a path (in the common sense of the word) for a random graph given by $t\mapsto X_t(\omega )$ (for fixed $\omega $ as you said). Just some stochastic processes defines something similar to "paths", like the Brownian motion (with the difference that the probability that a path of a Brownian motion between two distinct time stamps have infinite length is one, so it is neither completely a "path" in the common sense of the word)

Comment: @Masacroso Would you be able to elaborate on how $t \mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is not a path? I am having trouble seeing what is the difference between this and an ordinary path for a nonrandom function.

Comment: @CBBAM the notion of path, in ordinary language (not mathematics, just ordinary plain language) refers to a continuous thing, like a road. However, without further conditions, the function $t\mapsto X_t(\omega )$ doesn't need to be continuous, so the word "path" is somewhat misleading here. I hope you understand now about what I'm talking about.

Comment: To be fair, people do say stuff like Brownian paths all the time, and people do say paths for some discontinuous processes as well (e.g. Poisson jump processes or cadlag things in general).

Comment: @CBBAM Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be $N(0,1)$; then $Y(\omega) = -X(\omega)$ is also $N(0, 1)$ for example, but they don't match. Alternatively, it is probably a useful exercise to construct countably many independent variables on the probability space $[0,1]$ under the Lebesgue measure (hint: consider the dyadics and do countable uniform RVs first).

Comment: @daisies yes, but CBBAM is trying to get some **intuition**, and for intuition the term "path" is seriously misleading. This is why I'm talking about that

Comment: @Masacroso Oh yes I see now, I didn't even think about the nowhere continuity. Thank you!

Comment: @daisies Thank you, that example helped clear things up. So even if $X_t$ is identically distributed for each $t$ it does not mean that the maps are equal a.s. so the "paths" may not be constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually the same for random walks $S_{n}=\sum I_{k}$ for Gaussian $I_{k}\in N(0,1)$. Then if we normalize we get

$$X_{n}:=\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\sim N(0,1).$$

*"Since each $X_t$ is identically distributed, $X_t(\omega)$ is constant for all $t$ and fixed $\omega$."*

Here ,however, the $X_{n}$ are not constant. As we add more $I_{k}$ we fluctuate around zero. If we take a realization, we simply get a different path trajectory. The $\omega$ here means that we sample a realization of the path $(X_{t})_{t\geq 0}$. See for example [What is a sample path of a stochastic process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472068/what-is-a-sample-path-of-a-stochastic-process?rq=1) for many nice answers

[image]

Comment: Thank you! So the reason the paths $X_t(\omega)$ for fixed $\omega$ are not constant is because $X_t$ being identically distributed for all $t$ does not imply that $X_t = X_s$ for $t\neq s$. Is that the idea?

Comment: @CBBAM Yes because they differ by iid jumps Ik.